# Remote validation asp.net core telerik grid popup

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, telerik-grid, .net-5

I have a grid of `Countries`, in that I try to remote validate the `Code`, that should be unique.

```
public class CountryDTO
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    [Remote(action: "KeyExist", controller: "Countries")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I have in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CountryDTO.cshtml` the following

```
@model MyApp.Web.ApiModels.CountryDTO

<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Code" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Code" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Code" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
```

In the `CountriesController`:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public IActionResult KeyExist([Bind(Prefix ="Code")]string key)
    {
        if (_countriesService.KeyExist(key, id))
        {
            return Json($"The Code '{key}' is already used!");
        }

        return Json(true);
    }
```

but get this when I try to edit the code and leave:
[image]

The client request is the following, sending me the right code I tried to insert ("le" in that case)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by changing this [code](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/grid/how-to/editing/using-remote-validation-in-grid?_ga=2.74305750.55765961.1619297921-254013582.1613850306):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
```

to this one

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: postData,
```

in the Grid's CSHTML script tag.... (details on the client side script [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/grid/how-to/editing/using-remote-validation-in-grid?_ga=2.74305750.55765961.1619297921-254013582.1613850306))